# Why does it stop iterating after first value?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
def similarity(dna1, dna2):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(dna1)):
        if dna1.lower()[i] == dna2.lower()[i]:
            count += 1
    return count / len(dna1)

def best_match(dna_list, dna):
    for dna_seq in dna_list:
        dna1 = dna_seq
        dna2 = dna
        dict = {dna_seq: similarity(dna1, dna2)}
    return dict
```

In best_match I am given a list that contains dna sequences (dna_list). Using the above function I need to compare each sequence with the given dna (dna). Then return the dna sequence with the highest similarity. I was trying to create a dictionary to store the dna sequence with their similarity value and then comparing similarities and then returning the corresponding sequence. However, I am stuck. When I run this it returns only one dna sequence and that similarity value; however, I am given three dna sequences. I'm also having trouble because the list of given dna sequences (in dna_list) can vary.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, sorry

Comment: Since Python uses whitespace to denote blocks, and faulty whitespace causes `IndentationError`, you have to be very careful to paste correctly indented code here. If your indentation is incorrect, we don't know if this is an actual problem in your code or a copy/paste error.

Comment: All indentations are correct

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new dictionary at every iteration. It doesn't stop iterating, it is just returning the value from the last iteration, ignoring the previous ones.

What you want is this:

```
result = dict()
for dna_seq in dna_list:
    dna1 = dna_seq
    dna2 = dna
    result[dna_seq] = similarity(dna1, dna2)

return result
```

which can be written more briefly with dictionary comprehension:

```
return {dna_seq:similarity(dna_seq, dna) for dna_seq in dna_list}
```

Apart from that, you shouldn't call a variable `dict` because it shadows the built-in type `dict`.

Comment: Why initialize as `dict()` rather than `{}`?

Comment: Thank you that worked! (like mentioned I did change it to curly brackets) But can you please explain to me result[dna_seq] = similarity(dna1, dna2) ? Like how it works.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That's a matter of taste I think :) `dict` seems more explicit to me, so it is better for beginners. In general I don't mind `{}`.

Comment: @BartoszKP Definitely a style choice I respect either way. Just curious if there was some function behind the form I was missing.

Comment: @water847 See here for example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm and read dict's documentation :)

Comment: Ah, I get it ! Thank you guys so much :) before i try and realize it's not possible - is it possible to compare the similarity values then return the key with the highest value?

Comment: @water847 Not with a dict directly, but in general everything is possible :) If you have a different question then please post it as a new SO question. Remember to adhere to the rules ([help]) and provide a clear description of your problem, and after you're sure there isn't an answer already in a tutorial/the documentation :) Cheers!